# MPAndroidChart, Y-Axis Scale gets updated but lines are not

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). I have the following Activity - **StockDetail.Java**

```
 public class StockDetail extends AppCompatActivity{
     ArrayList<HistoricalData> historicalData=null;
 
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         SharedPreferences prefs=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("arrayList",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 
         try {
             historicalData = (ArrayList<HistoricalData>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(prefs.getString(
                     Utils.ARRAY_LIST, ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<HistoricalData>())));
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         setContentView(R.layout.stock_detail);
 
         LineChart lineChart=(LineChart) findViewById(R.id.lineChart);
 
 
         List<Entry> datas=new ArrayList<>();
         ArrayList<Float> floats=getDateInFloatValues(historicalData);
         HistoricalData hData;
         for (int i=0; i<historicalData.size(); i++) {
             hData=historicalData.get(i);
             datas.add(new Entry(floats.get(i),Float.parseFloat(hData.getHigh())));
         }
         LineDataSet lineDataSet=new LineDataSet(datas,"LineData");
         lineDataSet.setColor(R.color.material_red_700);
         LineData lineData=new LineData(lineDataSet);
         lineChart.setData(lineData);
         lineChart.invalidate();
     }
 }
```

The Y-Axis scale gets updated but there are no lines and Here is the screenshot:

[Image_1 Y-Axis scale updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WUs9.png)

It seems like there is some problem with my code, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem, i was using beta version of MPAndroidChart then i changed the app level build.gradle to

> compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5'

Everything works now