# Error when try add value on Array of BarEntry

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I have a little problem with [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). In the code above i get an error which are make me mad for 3 days.
Im getting an error when i try to add a entry to a barEntry array and i don no why.

```
private void retrive(){
    NoSQL.with(this).using(Float.class)
            .bucketId("MyMarket")
            .entityId("Chart")
            .retrieve(new RetrievalCallback<Float>() {
                @Override
                public void retrievedResults(List<NoSQLEntity<Float>> noSQLEntities) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < noSQLEntities.size(); i++) {
                        float item = noSQLEntities.get(i).getData();
                        BarEntry entry = new BarEntry(i, item);
                        barEntries.add(entry);

                    }
                }
            });

    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "Compras");

    BarData theData = new BarData(barDataSet);
    theData.setBarWidth(0.9f);
    barChart.setData(theData);

    barChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    barChart.setDragEnabled(true);
    barChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
    barChart.setDescription("");
    barChart.animateY(2700);
    barChart.setData(theData);
    barChart.setFitBars(true);

    XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);

    YAxis right = barChart.getAxisRight();
    right.setDrawGridLines(false);

    YAxis left = barChart.getAxisLeft();
    left.setDrawGridLines(false);

    barChart.invalidate();
}
```

In this line:

```
BarEntry entry = new BarEntry(i, item);
```

I have sure the value is added, but the program keep give me this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.stark.mymarket, PID: 6404
              java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
                  at com.github.mikephil.charting.buffer.BarBuffer.addBar(BarBuffer.java:37)
                  at com.github.mikephil.charting.buffer.BarBuffer.feed(BarBuffer.java:80)
                  at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.BarChartRenderer.drawDataSet(BarChartRenderer.java:103)
                  at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.BarChartRenderer.drawData(BarChartRenderer.java:78)
                  at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarLineChartBase.onDraw(BarLineChartBase.java:243)
                  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16178)
                  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
                  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2690)
                  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
                  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:281)
                  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:287)
                  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:322)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2615)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2434)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2067)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Make sure you're not using a beta version of MPAndroidChart. Per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736352/mpandroidchart-y-axis-scale-gets-updated-but-lines-are-not/39813637#39813637, there may be bugs

Answer (score 1):

You should look at your console log. Focusing on the line in which it says to you what kind of error you are getting:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0

which means that you are trying to access to a wrong position of your list, `noSQLEntities`.

You are getting the error on this line:

```
BarEntry entry = new BarEntry(i, item);
```

but I am almost secure that your error it is really on this other line (which is used on the line above):

```
float item = noSQLEntities.get(i).getData();
```

It seems that you are not initializing your `noSQLEntities` list with values so you are trying to access to a position of that list that does not exist.

Make sure that your `noSQLEntities` list have values. You can use [debug mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html) (if you are using Android Studio) or [`logs`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) to see the values of your `noSQLEntities` list in your console.